# Bar chart from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to create a Bar chart from a pandas df

The source file is an excel file with column headers: ‘Jan’, ‘Feb’,’Mar’...

The rows contain just values

When I created the df in pandas I then transposed the df and used df.plot()

However, I could not get any axis labels.

Any advice would be good

```
df1=read_excel(‘filename’)

df1 = df1.T

df1 = df1.sum(axis=‘columns’)

df1.plot()
```

The output should be a column name followed by the sum of all corresponding values in each column including a visual Bar chart.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `matplotlib` with data from your DataFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the case, but it works with me using the following code :

data5.txt :

```
Jan Feb Mar
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Then :

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('data/data5.txt', sep='\t')

df1 = df1.T
df1 = df1.sum(axis="columns")
ax = df1.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xlabel("Months")
ax.set_ylabel("Values")
ax.set_title("Title")
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you J.K - is it possible to add a graph total and axis labels? For instance ‘months’ / ‘values’. Also, is the method I used the best way to do it?